# Update one image without updating all the images

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm creating a simple gallery, I have database so that I can upload, update and delete a pictures. The upload, update and delete are already working. But I have problem on my update because every time I update one picture I also need to update all the pictures.

My question is how can I update one picture without updating all the pictures?

I think the problem is on my javascript but I'm not too familiar with it that’s why I can't figure it out. I also searched for possible solutions but still can't figure it out that's why I’m asking here.

[image]

> HTML Form

```
<form class="form-valide"  method="post" action="edit_query_maingallery.php?photo_id=<?php echo $fetch['photo_id'] ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="val-digits">Photo Description For Gallery: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <textarea name="photo_description" placeholder="Description" required="" rows="4" cols="50"><?php echo $fetch['photo_description'] ?></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="val-digits">Main Gallery Preview: <span class="text-danger"></span></label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <label>Main Photo </label>
            <div id = "preview" style = "width:150px; height :150px; border:1px solid #000;">
                <img src = "../photo/<?php echo $fetch['photo'] ?>" id = "lbl" width = "100%" height = "100%"/>
            </div>
            <input type = "file" required = "required" id = "photo" name = "photo" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="val-digits">Main Gallery Preview 1: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <label>Photo 1 </label>
            <div id = "preview1" style = "width:150px; height :150px; border:1px solid #000;">
                <img src = "../photo/<?php echo $fetch['photo1'] ?>" id = "lbl1" width = "100%" height = "100%"/>
            </div>
            <input type = "file" required = "required" id = "photo1" name = "photo1" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="val-digits">Main Gallery Preview 2: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <label>Photo 2 </label>
            <div id = "preview2" style = "width:150px; height :150px; border:1px solid #000;">
                <img src = "../photo/<?php echo $fetch['photo2'] ?>" id = "lbl2" width = "100%" height = "100%"/>
            </div>
            <input type = "file" required = "required" id = "photo2" name = "photo2" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="val-digits">Main Gallery Preview 3: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <label>Photo 3 </label>
            <div id = "preview3" style = "width:150px; height :150px; border:1px solid #000;">
                <img src = "../photo/<?php echo $fetch['photo3'] ?>" id = "lbl3" width = "100%" height = "100%"/>
            </div>
            <input type = "file" required = "required" id = "photo3" name = "photo3" />
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="val-digits">Main Gallery Preview 4: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <label>Photo 4 </label>
            <div id = "preview4" style = "width:150px; height :150px; border:1px solid #000;">
                <img src = "../photo/<?php echo $fetch['photo4'] ?>" id = "lbl4" width = "100%" height = "100%"/>
            </div>
            <input type = "file" required = "required" id = "photo4" name = "photo4" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 ml-auto">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="edit_maingallery">Update</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" name="cancel"><a href="view_maingallery.php">Cancel</a></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

> JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $pic = $('<img id = "image" width = "100%" height = "100%"/>');
  $lbl = $('<center id = "lbl">[Photo]</center>');
  $("#photo").change(function () {
    $("#lbl").remove();
    var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
    if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) {
      $("#image").remove();
      $lbl.appendTo("#preview");
    }
    if (/^image/.test(files[0].type)) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
      reader.onloadend = function () {
        $pic.appendTo("#preview");
        $("#image").attr("src", this.result);
      };
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  $pic1 = $('<img id = "image1" width = "100%" height = "100%"/>');
  $lbl1 = $('<center id = "lbl1">[Photo]</center>');
  $("#photo1").change(function () {
    $("#lbl1").remove();
    var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
    if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) {
      $("#image1").remove();
      $lbl1.appendTo("#preview1");
    }
    if (/^image/.test(files[0].type)) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
      reader.onloadend = function () {
        $pic1.appendTo("#preview1");
        $("#image1").attr("src", this.result);
      };
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  $pic2 = $('<img id = "image2" width = "100%" height = "100%"/>');
  $lbl2 = $('<center id = "lbl2">[Photo]</center>');
  $("#photo2").change(function () {
    $("#lbl2").remove();
    var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
    if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) {
      $("#image2").remove();
      $lbl2.appendTo("#preview2");
    }
    if (/^image/.test(files[0].type)) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
      reader.onloadend = function () {
        $pic2.appendTo("#preview2");
        $("#image2").attr("src", this.result);
      };
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  $pic3 = $('<img id = "image3" width = "100%" height = "100%"/>');
  $lbl3 = $('<center id = "lbl3">[Photo]</center>');
  $("#photo3").change(function () {
    $("#lbl3").remove();
    var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
    if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) {
      $("#image3").remove();
      $lbl3.appendTo("#preview3");
    }
    if (/^image/.test(files[0].type)) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
      reader.onloadend = function () {
        $pic3.appendTo("#preview3");
        $("#image3").attr("src", this.result);
      };
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  $pic4 = $('<img id = "image4" width = "100%" height = "100%"/>');
  $lbl4 = $('<center id = "lbl4">[Photo]</center>');
  $("#photo4").change(function () {
    $("#lbl4").remove();
    var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
    if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) {
      $("#image4").remove();
      $lbl4.appendTo("#preview4");
    }
    if (/^image/.test(files[0].type)) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
      reader.onloadend = function () {
        $pic4.appendTo("#preview4");
        $("#image4").attr("src", this.result);
      };
    }
  });
});
```

> PHP

```
<?php include 'connect.php';

$current_date = date('Y-m-d');

if (isset($_POST["edit_maingallery"])) {
    extract($_POST);
    $photo_description = $_POST['photo_description'];

    $photo = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']));
    $photo1 = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name']));
    $photo2 = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['photo2']['tmp_name']));
    $photo3 = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['photo3']['tmp_name']));
    $photo4 = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['photo4']['tmp_name']));

    $photo_name = addslashes($_FILES['photo']['name']);
    $photo_name1 = addslashes($_FILES['photo1']['name']);
    $photo_name2 = addslashes($_FILES['photo2']['name']);
    $photo_name3 = addslashes($_FILES['photo3']['name']);
    $photo_name4 = addslashes($_FILES['photo4']['name']);

    $photo_size = getimagesize($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], "../photo/" . $_FILES['photo']['name']);

    $sq1 = "UPDATE `gallery` SET `photo_description` = '$photo_description', `photo` = '$photo_name', `photo1` = '$photo_name1', `photo2` = '$photo_name2', `photo3` = '$photo_name3', `photo4` = '$photo_name4' WHERE `photo_id` = '" . $_GET['photo_id'] . "'";
    if ($conn->query($sq1) === true) {
        $_SESSION['success'] = ' Record Successfully Updated';
        ?>
           <script type="text/javascript">
           window.location="view_maingallery.php";
           </script>
       <?php
    } else {
            $_SESSION['error'] = 'Something Went Wrong';
            ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                window.location="view_maingallery.php";
                </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that if you update 1 picture, all the rest are then blank?

Comment: It should also be noted that you are only calling `move_uploaded_file` for 1 photo.

Comment: Yes, I can update one picture only if I remove the required attribute in html form, but the other pictures are blank.

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL is currently overwriting your existing images with blank values.

You need to update your query to check if each photo is empty or not before you add it into the query.

---

**Existing Query:**

```
$sq1="UPDATE `gallery` SET `photo_description` = '$photo_description', `photo` = '$photo_name', `photo1` = '$photo_name1', `photo2` = '$photo_name2', `photo3` = '$photo_name3', `photo4` = '$photo_name4' WHERE `photo_id` = '".$_GET['photo_id']."'";
```

**New Query:**

```
$sql="UPDATE `gallery` SET `photo_description` = '$photo_description'";
if(!empty($photo_name)) $sql.=", `photo` = '$photo_name' ";
if(!empty($photo_name1)) $sql.=", `photo1` = '$photo_name1' ";
if(!empty($photo_name2)) $sql.=", `photo2` = '$photo_name2' ";
if(!empty($photo_name3)) $sql.=", `photo3` = '$photo_name3' ";
if(!empty($photo_name4)) $sql.=", `photo4` = '$photo_name4' ";
$sql.="WHERE `photo_id` = '".$_GET['photo_id']."'";
```

---

You're also calling your variable "sq1" and not "sql", one uses the number one and the other uses a lowercase L, just for ease of use it's better to use the letter L, so in addition to copying the above you'll also need to change the variable name here:

```
if ($conn->query($sq1) === TRUE)
```

to:

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
```

Comment: Only the photo description works but all the photo descriptions have been updated instead of just the id you are looking for should be updated. I think only the first line works.

Comment: There was a bug in my code that I've now fixed, try again?

Comment: I know it's a bug I already try it ($photo_name) and I also try this ("$photo_name"), ('$photo_name') still the same output only the photo description works.

Comment: Oh I see the issue - your variable is called "sq1" and the variable I'm using is "sql", so one uses the number one and the other uses a lowercase L

Comment: It’s working now. Thank you very much and Stay Safe!

Comment: No problem - remember to mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should refactor your code. You have a lot of mess in your code.

First, you should remove duplicate code in HTML, JS, PHP files.

For HTML file. Please create a template for row with picture:

```
 <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="val-digits">Main Gallery Preview: <span class="text-danger"></span></label>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <label>Main Photo </label>
       <div id = "preview" style = "width:150px; height :150px; border:1px solid #000;"> 
        <img src = "../photo/<?php echo $fetch['photo']?>" id = "lbl" width = "100%" height = "100%"/> 
      </div>
      <input type = "file" required = "required" id = "photo" name = "photo" />
    </div>
```

For JS file. Please create a function to make interactions with your row.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $pic3 = $('<img id = "image3" width = "100%" height = "100%"/>');
    $lbl3 = $('<center id = "lbl3">[Photo]</center>');
    $("#photo3").change(function(){
        $("#lbl3").remove();
        var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
        if(!files.length || !window.FileReader){
            $("#image3").remove();
            $lbl3.appendTo("#preview3");
        }
        if(/^image/.test(files[0].type)){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
            reader.onloadend = function(){
                $pic3.appendTo("#preview3");
                $("#image3").attr("src", this.result);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

You should pass only one argument `rowId`.

For PHP code. You should create function for upload image in your gallery. And call that method like `uploadImageToGallery($imageId)`.

```
    function uploadImageToGallery($imageId) {
        $photo = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['photo' . $imageId]['tmp_name']));
        $photo_name = addslashes($_FILES['photo' . $imageId]['name']);
        $photo_size = getimagesize($_FILES['photo'  . $imageId]['tmp_name']);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo' . $imageId]['tmp_name'],"../photo/" . $_FILES['photo' . $imageId]['name']);
        
        $sq1="UPDATE `gallery` SET `photo" .  . $imageId . "` = '$photo_name' WHERE `photo_id` = '".$_GET['photo_id']."'";
        $conn->query($sq1)
    }
```

It's example. How you should refactoring your code!

P.S. You should check which element of array $_FILES exist, and apply that method for that element of array $_FILES.